# Is there an Object Oriented programming language without procedural programming?

Tags: oop, architecture, coding-style, programming-languages

As we have pure procedural programming languages, are there programming languages that are pure OOPS?

Comment: To make answers not "pure opinion", responders please argue their take.

Comment: First you will have to provide an acceptable definition of 'pure OOPS'. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

Some functional languages have Object Oriented features.

Some of these languages are purely functional:

- [Timber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timber_(programming_language)) (extension of Haskell)

Some can be used as purely functional, but support also procedural style:

- [OCaml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCaml) (extension of Caml and Caml light)
- [CLOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp_Object_System) (extension of Lisp)

Answer (score 0):

William Cook, in [On Understanding Data Abstraction, Revisited](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf), said: "*One of the most pure object-oriented programming models yet defined is the Component Object Model*" ([Microsoft COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model)) since there is no way to inspect the representation of objects, no built-in notion of equality, and no way to determine if an object is an instance of a given class.